# Append query result to a existing json object

Tags: php, json, laravel, object, laravel-5.3

i have the result of 2 query in 2 variables and i have a `JSON` object i want to `append` the query result to that JSON and then return it to the user

in may controller i have all the result

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {

    $agent_id = $request->user()->id;

    $drivers_cout = Driver::all()->count();

    $drivers_cout_by_agent = Driver::where(['agent_id' => $agent_id])->get()->count();

    return $request->user();
}

//the result of  $request->user();

  #attributes: array:12 [
    "id" => 201702
    "name" => "Agent"
    "email" => "agent@gmail.com"
    "phone_number" => "966355826"
  ]

//and i want something like

  #attributes: array:12 [
    "id" => 201702
    "name" => "Agent"
    "email" => "agent@gmail.com"
    "phone_number" => "966355826"
    "drivers_count" => "96"                        //How do i append these two
    "drivers_cout_by_agent" => "16"         
  ]
```

thank you

Comment: Try this: [Serializing Models & Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding data to an array is simply a case of putting data into the array with the index name you want it to have

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {

    $agent_id = $request->user()->id;              

    $drivers_count = Driver::all()->count();         //<-- fixed spelling

    $drivers_cout_by_agent = Driver::where(['agent_id' => $agent_id])->get()->count();

    $arr = $request->user();
    $arr['drivers_count'] = $drivers_count;
    $arr['drivers_cout_by_agent'] = $drivers_cout_by_agent
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: I see that i have overcomplicated this a little bit ;D

Comment: @PatrykUszyński   i sry din't get  what you said, did you mean the way i'm doing is not right, please correct me for best practice, i a kinda newbi, thank you

Comment: No other guy was commenting on his answer being a little more info than you required

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an array and just want to add a few elements to it, so this can do it.

```
$tmp= $request->user();
$tmp['driver_count'] = (where you get it from);
$tmp['count_by_id'] = (where you get it from);
return $tmp;
```

(Sorry for lack of detail, I'm on my cell. If this is what you need, I'll expand/correct later or delete if it's not.  Wanted to get this to you quickly.)

Comment: thank you so much for your time really appreciate it, i got the solution

Comment: A few minutes too late, I see! Cell phone slowed me down. :) I'll delete the answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Serializing Models & Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#serializing-models-and-collections). You can simply serialize it json or array by:

```
return $request->user()->toJson();
// or
return $request->user()->toArray();
```

There is also a section about appending data to json: [Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json). But in your situation you can serialize your data to array, append your values and encapsulate it to json.

```
$returnData = $request->user()->toArray();
$returnData['foo'] = 'bar';

return json_encode($returnData);
```

Comment: thank you for your response, actually i want to append the query result to json object